# How to update the model from the ajax by rest framework(csrf problem??)

Tags: django, ajax

I want to update the table row by from ajax

From auto generated form (by rest framweorks) posting and updating works correctly.

However from ajax it shows

`"POST /api/issues/372/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58` error

I googled around and found that this is related with `csrt`.

However How can I send correct json???

```
var json = {
         "id": 37;
         "name": "This is my new name",
         "color": "#dddddd"
};


$.ajax({
        type:"POST",            
        url: "{% url 'issues-detail' 372 %}",    
        data:JSON.stringify(json),  
        contentType: 'application/JSON', 
        dataType: "JSON",       
        success: function(response) {  
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {  
            console.log(response);      
        },
        complete: function() {   
            console.log("complete");
        }
});
```

Comment: `"HTTP 403 Forbidden"` - CSRF, Cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this code to your js file in document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({

    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) 
      {
        // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie("csrftoken"));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

For sending POST request we need to set csrf-token.